# How to save image from android to java server

Tags: java, android, mysql, image

I need to upload an image from android app to a java server. I tried to define the type image like a string and to convert the image, that the user can upload from documents or take with camera, into a base64 string. But when i convert this image in base64 and put this inside a string to save it in database, server give me a 500 internal sever error and this error message: 
"com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'image' at row 1" 
The Db is in Mysql and i use this from java server.
So, how can I save a base64 image to my server? Can I use a different type?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you're currently doing? Also, what is the Data Type for the column 'image'? An image converted into a String can be quite long, and judging from that error, the Data Type you're using for that column isn't one that can hold a very long String of text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use volley library. for more details these links are useful
[first_link](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/) and [second_link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/upload-image-to-server/)